# Alternative to a function pointer with reference capture

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm writing an event handler that listens for key presses, then calls a handler on any pressed keys. My goal was to allow something like this:

```
Entity player(0, 0);

EventHandler eh([&](char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'W': {
            player.moveBy(0,-1);
            break;
        }
        case 'S': {
            player.moveBy(0, 1);
            break;
        }
        case 'A': {
            player.moveBy(-1, 0);
            break;
        }
        case 'D': {
            player.moveBy(1, 0);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

where an `Entity` is just a movable point-like object.

I was all set, then I realized that lambdas with referential captures can't be made into a function pointer (the reason makes sense, in retrospect).

The only alternative I could find was to use `std::`/`boost::function`, but the syntax is rather ugly, and apparently they come with a decent amount of overhead.

What's a good alternative to this system? I want to be able to pass in some kind of "handler" to `EventHandler` that accepts a character, and is capable of carrying out side effects on some external scope.

In the below source, `LockedQueue` is a FIFO queue that's been made thread safe using `mutex`es.

EventHandler.h:

```
#ifndef EVENT_HANDLER_H
#define EVENT_HANDLER_H

#include <vector>
#include <atomic>

#include "LockedQueue.h"

class EventHandler {

    typedef void(*KeyHandler)(char);

    std::atomic<bool> listenOnKeys = false;

    std::vector<char> keysToCheck;

    LockedQueue<char> pressedKeys;

    KeyHandler keyHandler = nullptr;

    void updatePressedKeys();

    void actOnPressedKeys();

public:
    EventHandler();
    EventHandler(KeyHandler);

    ~EventHandler();

    void setKeyHandler(KeyHandler);

    void setKeysToListenOn(std::vector<char>);

    void listenForPresses(int loopMSDelay = 100);
    void stopListening();

};

#endif
```

EventHandler.cpp:

```
#include "EventHandler.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <thread>
#include <stdexcept>

EventHandler::EventHandler() {

}

EventHandler::EventHandler(KeyHandler handler) {
    keyHandler = handler;
}

EventHandler::~EventHandler() {
    stopListening();
}

void EventHandler::updatePressedKeys() {
    for (char key : keysToCheck) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(key)) {
            pressedKeys.push(key);
        }
    }
}

void EventHandler::actOnPressedKeys() {
    while (!pressedKeys.empty()) {
        //Blocking if the queue is empty
        //We're making sure ahead of time though that it's not
        keyHandler(pressedKeys.waitThenPop());
    }
}

void EventHandler::setKeyHandler(KeyHandler handler) {
    keyHandler = handler;
}

void EventHandler::setKeysToListenOn(std::vector<char> newListenKeys) {
    if (listenOnKeys) {
        throw std::runtime_error::runtime_error(
            "Cannot change the listened-on keys while listening"
        );
        //This could be changed to killing the thread by setting
        // listenOnKeys to false, changing the keys, then restarting
        // the listening thread. I can't see that being necessary though.
    }

    //To-Do:
    //Make sure all the keys are in upper-case so they're
    // compatible with GetAsyncKeyState

    keysToCheck = newListenKeys;

}

void EventHandler::listenForPresses(int loopMSDelay) {
    listenOnKeys = true;
    std::thread t([&]{
        do {
            updatePressedKeys();
            actOnPressedKeys();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(loopMSDelay));
        } while (listenOnKeys);
    });
    t.join();
}

void EventHandler::stopListening() {
    listenOnKeys = false;
}
```

EDIT:

Whoops. Note that `listenForPresses` is "broken" because I'm joining inside the function, so control never leaves it. I'm going to need to figure out a workaround. Doesn't change the question though, but the code isn't testable in it's current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only alternative I could find was to use std::/boost::function, but the syntax is rather ugly, and apparently they come with a decent amount of overhead.

The overhead is decent compared to an inlinable function, but [it's measured in nanoseconds](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/function/faq.html#id1284915). If you're only calling the function 60 times a second, the overhead is immeasurable.

That said, if you need to be able to change the event handler at any time, your only alternative is virtual method calls, with similar overhead. The performance impact of these choices are explored thoroughly in this article: [Member Function Pointers and the Fastest Possible C++ Delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible).

If you are happy to restrict the EventHandler object to executing a single block of code defined at compile-time, use templates to store an instance of the compiler's generated type for the lambda; this should allow the compiler to perform more optimisations, as it can know for sure what code is being called. In this case, `KeyHandler` becomes a template type, and the type of a lambda can either be found with the `decltype` keyword:

```
template <class KeyHandler>
class EventHandler {
    // elided
}

void EventLoopDecltype() {
    Entity player(0, 0);
    auto myEventHandler = [&](char ch) { /* elided */ };
    EventHandler<decltype(myEventHandler)> eh(myEventHandler);
}
```

or (more conveniently, for the caller) inferred as an argument to a template function:

```
template <class KeyHandler>
EventHandler<KeyHandler> MakeEventHandler(KeyHandler handler) {
    return EventHandler<KeyHandler>(handler);
}

void EventLoopInferred() {
    Entity player(0, 0);

    auto eh = MakeEventHandler([&](char c) {
        // elided
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I only need a static chuck of code; I won't need to do any key "re-binding" during run-time. I don't understand what you're talking about regarding templates though. I know templates as something used for generic programming; to represent a type. How does that help me "plug-in" a chunk of code? Is there a specific name for this technique?

Comment: I've re-read your post a couple times, and I still don't get you last paragraph. Could you give me a super-minimal piece of code to demonstrate it please?

Comment: Demonstrated both approaches using the template class. You can of course use a function object, which requires less magic (it's a class you define yourself with operaror()) but you must manually capture the values you require.

Comment: You both said that the overhead for `std::function` is negligible, so I think I'll try that. If it doesn't work for whatever reason, I'll try one of your other methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`std::function` and `boost::function` do not come with any overhead that's remotely meaningful considering how light your usage of them would be in this case. You've made a critical error by discarding the solution before determining that the purported downsides actually apply to you.

You could of course also use a template as described in the other answer, but there's really no need to.

Comment: Hopefully seeing how much more work it is to do so will dissuade you from doing so unless you really know you need it!